# Multisite - Parent site with Polylang with different domains for each language

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, plugin-polylang

A client wants a Wordpress multisite installation where they will have over 100 child sites. The child sites will either have its own domain or use the subdomain. This is all fine and good but now he's requesting that the parent site to have both English and French using Polylang plugin and have a different domain for each.

Example: http://ParentSite.com and http://ParentSiteFrench.com will both go the the main site of the network but ParentSiteFrench.com will show only the FR pages from Polylang.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [plugin description](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/), this should be possible:

> you can use one different subdomain or domain per language

You would need to activate the plugin on the main site only. It is best to test the whole thing on some testing multisite environment.